# Update a cell value with Row and Column number for use in indirect function based on which cell is selected

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a spreadsheet similar to below

[image: spreadsheet]

Where when I click on a cell (red cell), I want to return the row and column number to another cell for use in an indirect lookup (blue cell)

Ideally I want to only update the cell value if it's within a set range or at least limit it only to that worksheet for error handling.

Hope that's clear... not an easy thing to google.  My experiments with

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

Have returned nothing, not even a message box even though macros run fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `ActiveCell`. Use **`Target.Row`** and **`Target.Column`**

Comment: @Zac - Since only one cell can be used here, ActiveCell is valid but I prefer Target.cells(1) or the simpler Target(1).

Comment: On Note: avoid the use of `INDIRECT`, just have the code do the whole step as one.  `INDIRECT` is volatile, and it is a waste of time.  Have the code do it all.

Comment: @Jeeped: I agree that in this instance, `ActiveCell` will probably work but as `Good Practice`, I always advice against it purely because it can be very volatile and cause issues that you wouldn't expect. `Target(1)` is much better approach.. just my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example. Make sure your code is in the appropriate sheet module, not a standard module and make sure Application.EnableEvents=True (your existing code should have done something).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Intersect(Target(1), Range("C4:H9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Range("J3").Value = Cells(Target(1).Row, 2) & "," & Cells(3, Target(1).Column)

End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner - based on the pic, it will return 3,3 I think?

Comment: Cheers, restarted and everything worked.  Obviously just one of those things!

Answer (score 2):

Use this in the worksheet's private code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Range("C4:H9")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C4:H9").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Cells(3, "J") = Join(Array(Cells(Target.Cells(1).Row, "B"), _
                                   Cells(3, Target.Cells(1).Column)), Chr(44))
        Target.Cells(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks there's a couple of bits which'll improve my solution :)